# How do I maximize Skype from Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-7, skype

I am trying to maximize my skype window from powershell.

I use the following script...

```
$sig = '[DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);'
Add-Type -MemberDefinition $sig -name NativeMethods -namespace Win32
$hwnd = @(Get-Process lync)[0].MainWindowHandle
# Restore window
[Win32.NativeMethods]::ShowWindowAsync($hwnd, 4)
```

I also tried

```
$hwnd = @(Get-Process -id 2560)[0].MainWindowHandle
```

Info

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      14409  1012
```

But when I run the command it doesn't maximize, just returns true. Can I maximize a Skype window from poershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close in your question statement, but you are [using the wrong constant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548(v=vs.85).aspx).

```
$SW_MAXIMIZE = 3
$sig = @'
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
'@
Add-Type -MemberDefinition $sig -Name Functions -Namespace Win32

$hWnd = (Get-Process -Name lync).MainWindowHandle
[Win32.Functions]::ShowWindow($hWnd, $SW_MAXIMIZE)
```